# Spark:How to compare two rdd by key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to compare two rdd by their common keys. So I filter the rdd by `key` firstly, then compare the sub rdds.

For examples,

```
def compare(rdd1,rdd2):
    do_something()
    
rdd = sc.textFile(path1) # each Rdd is dict type
rdd2 = sc.textFile(path2)
pair_rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.keys()).zip(rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x.values()))
pair_rdd2 = rdd2.flatMap(lambda x: x.keys()).zip(rdd2.flatMap(lambda x:x.values()))
for feat in set(pair_rdd.keys().distinct().collect()) & \
            set(pair_rdd2.keys().distinct().collect()):
    pair_rdd_filter = pair_rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] == feat).map(lambda x:x[1])
    pair_rdd_filter2 = pair_rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] == feat).map(lambda x:x[1])
    compare(pair_rdd_filter, pair_rdd_filter2)
```

For convenience, I give an example of the `rdd`.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([{'f':[1,2,3]},{'f':[1,20],'a':[1]}])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([{'f':[3,4],'a':[23]},{'f':[2,100,10,2],'a':[3,10,3],'b':[3]}])
```

But, I find that if using `collect()` to get common keys, the `rdd` will start to `reduce`, which costs much time.

How to make this code run effectively.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is calling `.collect()` will move all the data to driver which then does the set intersection. To utilise distributed execution, use [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.join) instead:

```
pair_rdd.join(pair_rdd2)
```

This will output a RDD with common keys and values as tuple `(pair_rdd element, pair_rdd2 element)`

It can also be used to e.g. get common keys:

```
pair_rdd.join(pair_rdd2).keys().distinct()
```

Comment: Then how to compare the sub `rdd` with same key?

Comment: Improved the answer

Comment: I find that the joined rdd has multi same keys, and it will still need to `reduce` firstly.  Do you mean this `join_rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1]) ).map(lambda x: compare(x[0], x[1]))`?